# Recover or reset local login information managed by the Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems

I recently inherited a small Ruby on Rails platform that was more or less abandoned by its previous developer. It uses the Devise gem for user authentication/management/privileges. I have the administrative login for the live version of the platform online, but I don't know the administrative login if I just run the server locally via bin/rails server. I can't get into contact with the previous web developer.

My question is, how do I gain administrative privileges via the Devise gem when I don't have the administrative login for the local version of the application? Is there a way to reset the users managed by the Devise gem or add a new user with administrative privileges without knowing the login information of a current administrator? I need to be able to easily view pages that are only visible to users with elevated privileges without having to do a full deploy and then inspect the changes online.

Comment: try using rails console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open up `rails console`.

1. Take a look at `user.rb` model and what roles does a user can have. Is there any `role_id` attribute in `users` table ? or just any boolean attributes like this `admin`.
2. In rails console, you can find an admin based on the step 2 findings.
   Suppose, user with `id = 1` have an admin attribute then you can write in console

   `user = User.find(1)
    user.admin? #true`
3. Then you can setup the new password for this user like this

   `user.password = '1234test'
    user.password_confirmation = 1234test
    user.skip_confirmation #if confirmable is enabled
    user.save!'`

**For Enums**
As mentioned [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

> Declare an enum attribute where the values map to integers in the database, but can be queried by name

1. You have mentioned that roles is an `enum` with the possible roles as `:customer, :mechanic, and :admin` which means in rails console, if you type `User.roles`, it will return all the roles mapped with indexes like this
   `User.roles # => { "customer" => 0, "mechanic" => 1, "admin" => 2 }`
2. In order to give any `role` to any `user` from `console`, you need to provide the index(integer) to that `user` like this:

   `u = User.find(1)
    u.role = 0 # it needs integer here not symbols
    u.save
    u.role  # => "customer"`

Comment: This has been really helpful--I successfully created a new user. However, I'm having difficulty setting my role to :admin.  In user.rb, roles: is an enum, with the possible values :customer, :mechanic, and :admin. There is an attribute shown when I say r = User.find(1) [1 is my id] called :role, and if I input r.role = :admin, it returns ":admin", but then my role attribute is still set to nil after r.save! and I can't view the privileged pages in the app. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

If you know the user id of the admin user you can just go into the console and reset it manually.

```
admin_user = User.find(7)
```

or if you only know the email

```
admin_user = User.where(:email => 'admin@email.com').last
```

or

```
admin_users = User.where(admin: true) #sort through the results and pick one

admin_user.password = 'my_new_password'
admin_user.password_confirmation = 'my_new_password'
admin_user.save(:validate =>) #in the event there are validation issues
```

You also have the option of just creating a new admin user

```
admin_user = User.new
admin_user.admin = true
admin_user.email = 'your@email.com'
admin_user.password = 'my_new_password'
admin_user.password_confirmation = 'my_new_password'
admin_user.save
```